# Yesod css - not in scope variable

Tags: haskell, yesod

I initialize Yesod project from template.
I got error when try change css variable at Foundation.hs

```
$ stack new s1 yesod-simple
$ cd s1
$ mv static/css/bootstrap.css static/css/style.css
```

Change **Foundation.hs**

```
pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
    addStylesheet $ StaticR css_bootstrap_css
    $(widgetFile "default-layout")
```

to

```
     pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
         addStylesheet $ StaticR css_style_css
         $(widgetFile "default-layout")

$ stack build
...
[4 of 8] Compiling Foundation       ( Foundation.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/Foundation.o )

Foundation.hs:64:37: Not in scope: ‘css_style_css’
```

But as I know at compile time css_style_css should automatically appeared.
What I do wrong? And what can I do if we need added several css files to default layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your Cabal file
2. FInd block:

> ```
> if flag(dev) || flag(library-only)
>     cpp-options:   -DDEVELOPMENT
>     ghc-options:   -Wall -fwarn-tabs -O0
> else
>     ghc-options:   -Wall -fwarn-tabs -O2
> ```

and add **-fforce-recomp** to **ghc-options** for needed line.

Comment: In recent templates this has to be added to the `package.yaml` file, as the cabal file is generated automatically.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Yesod tutorial](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/yesod_tutorial-filling_in_the_layout):

> Whenever you modify your static folder, touch StaticFiles.hs and you
>   should be good to go.
>
> So, run this command in the console:
>
> `touch Settings/StaticFiles.hs`

The `StaticFiles.hs` file needs to be compiled in order to have the `css_style_css` definition. If you modify you static folder, this file is out of sync with the folder content but GHC/Stack has no mean to find out.